# how does one approach this problem on DSA

Tags: algorithm

Two arrays are given of length n and two numbers c and d.
Find the count of all pairs that follow the condition : a[i]-a[j]+c <= b[i]-b[j]+d such that i < j.

I have been thinking about it for hours and I don't know how to approach the problem. My initial thought was hashing the array to save me from any O(n^2)

Comment: Are your arrays sorted ?

Comment: I am not sure it is sorted

Answer (score 0):

I will describe a O(n * log n) time complexity solution.

Firstly, notice your condition is equivalent to a[i]-b[i] <= a[j]-b[j]+x, where x is a number.

Consider the array f such that f[i] = a[i] - b[i].

The condition is equivalent to f[i] <= f[j] + x.

To count the number of pair satisfying this condition, you can use divide and conquer: break the array in two halves recursively. The total count is the number of pairs satisfying the condition in the first half (let it be q1) plus the number of pairs satisfying the condition in the second half (let it be q2) plus the number of pairs satisfying the condition with one element in the first half and the other one in the second half (let it be q12).

The trick is that q12 in the original array is equal to q12 if both halves are sorted. But if both halves are sorted, you can count q12 in O(n) (proof left as exercise). So, the divide and conquer recursion follows the inequality T(n) <= 2*T(n/2) + O(n). By the [master theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)), you can conclude the time complexity is O(n * log n).